# IndexError: Out of bounds for test case 1 and 2; using a try-except block to prevent the program from crashing when value3 > value1

Tags: python

Create a function that takes in three arguments and prints one integer.

- Random seed should be set to 42.
- First argument should correspond to the size of a np.randint - values from 0 to 10.
- Second argument is an integer that you will multiply the randint by.
- The third argument is a value you will index the result of the multiplication
  by.

Print the integer that was indexed as ‘Your random value is k’

k = the result of the indexing

**The program should not crash if the third value is larger than the first; it should not print anything to the screen.**

**Code**

```
import sys
import numpy
import random

numpy.random.seed(42)
value1 = int(sys.argv[1])
value2 = int(sys.argv[2])
value3 = int(sys.argv[3])


def randomized(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    x = numpy.random.randint(0, 10, size=arg1)
    y = x * arg2
    return y[arg3]


try:
    random_value = randomized(value1, value2, value3)
    print(f"Your random value is {random_value}")
except IndexError:
    pass

randomized(value1, value2, value3)
```

**Test Case Examples:**

```
python3 reallyrandom.py 1 2 9 
python3 reallyrandom.py 44 3 17
python3 reallyrandom.py 77 -3 55
python3 reallyrandom.py 2 4 10
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Your random value is 21
Your random value is -9
```

**Error Message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reallyrandom.py", line 23, in <module>
    randomized(value1, value2, value3)
  File "reallyrandom.py", line 14, in randomized
    return y[arg3]
IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Comment: Your error message doesn't match your code.

Comment: You are calling `randomize` twice in your code, once inside the `try ... except` block and once at the bottom. The exception raised in the second call will not be caught and so will generate the exception traceback you see. Try deleting the second call to `randomize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *The program should not crash if the third value is larger than the first; **it should not print anything to the screen***

So, the error `raise`d is an `IndexError`, right? You can prevent your code from printing anything using a `try`/`except` block, like this:

```
try:
    # Your code
except IndexError:
    pass # Nothing gets printed
```

Comment: It's impossible to get an IndexError from a call inside a try/except block that catches an IndexError... maybe the error is caused by the last line of your code which isn't into the block